# Lookup field value in CAML, Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I am using the .NET Client Object Model from a website to access data in a SharePoint list.  One of the fields I am trying to access is a lookup field. How do I get the text for the lookup field using a join in the CAML query?

I have read so far that joins are not supported in CAML in the Client Object Model. Is this true?

The issue is doctype comes back with a message saying it is a lookup field.

It is not possible for me to use the SharePoint Server Object Model.

Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SPServer_DigAssts"].ToString());

List list = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Leases");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

camlQuery.ViewXml = "@<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='BuildingId'/><Value Type='Text'>" + bid.ToString() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

_clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(item => item["BuildingId"], item => item["DocType"], item => item.DisplayName));

_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems) 
{
    DataRow r = dtbl.NewRow();
    r["BuildingId"] = listItem["BuildingId"];
    r["Name"] = listItem.DisplayName;
    r["DocType"] = listItem["DocType"];
    dtbl.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to read the lookupvalue

```
var docType= listItem["DocType"] as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue;
string value = docType.LookupValue;
```